# Getting error on custom add to cart Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, javascript, addtocart, jquery

I am trying to submit custom add to cart on product page with configurable product options but i am getting error with that.My code looks like this :

```
<script>
 jQuery("#submit").click(function () {
var color = jQuery('#colors').val();
var qty = jQuery('#qty').val();;
var size = jQuery('#sizes').val();;
alert(window.location.href = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>checkout/cart/add?product=<?php echo $current_product_id; ?>&qty='+ qty + '&super_attribute[139]='+ size +'&super_attribute[141]='+ color+'');
 window.location.href = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>checkout/cart/add?product=<?php echo $current_product_id; ?>&qty='+ qty + '&super_attribute[139]='+ size +'&super_attribute[141]='+ color+'';
});
</script>
```

where `139` and `141` are the attributes ids.I am getting the error `Please specify the product's option(s).`what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I have the similar problem, help me if you got your answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/cannot-add-configurable-product-to-cart-progrmatically

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you would need to include the formkey in the add URL for this to work? e.g

```
e.g &form_key=<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>
```